# rewrite condition does not work

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In my `php`-project, I have the following folder structure.

```
/ [root]
|-- ... [some other folders]
|-- util/            // containing js,css files; should be accessible for anyone.
|-- client/          
    |--data/         // contains files which can be uploaded by users
       |-- private/  // should only be accessible for logged in users
       |-- public/   // should be accessible for anyone.
|-- ... [some other folders]
|-- index.php
```

I want to achieve the following behaviour:

1. If someone directly access to anything within util/ he should just get what he has requested, if it's not an directory.
2. If someone wants to access any file within `client/` it should be redirected to index.php.
   For example someone enters the url `www.test.com/client/data/private/test.jpg` the server should get the request as `index.php?request1=client/data/private/test.jpg`.
3. Everything else should be rewritten to `index.php?request2=$1`

I am not able to get point 2 function as per the expectation.

I use the following  .htaccess file, to handle this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# allow access to all files within util/  WORKS!!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)(util)($|/) - [L]

# here i have problems.. how can i achieve, that access to folder client/ is rewritten to index.php?request1=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^client
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?request1=$1 [QSA,L]

# rewriting everything else   WORKS!!
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?request2=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What should happen with `/client/dir1/dir2` where a specific _file_ wasn't requested? Should that be rewritten to index.php, or should directory access be unmodified?

Comment: this should either be caught by RewriteRule 3 or throw one of these http errors 401, 404. but i would prefer Rule 3

Comment: Ah wait a minute -- `REQUEST_URI` should probably have a leading `/` when matching as `^/client` since that's how the header would be structured. That is in contrast to how `RewriteRule` expects to match in a directory context. Give that a try, and that may be all you need. Everything else looks right to me.

Comment: that did not work either... but thanks

Comment: Turn on rewrite logging and start debugging, I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# allow access to all files within util/  WORKS!!
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^util($|/) - [L]

# here i have problems.. how can i achieve, that access to folder client/ is rewritten to index.php?request1=$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^client(/.*|)$ index.php?request1=$1 [QSA,L]

# rewriting everything else WORKS!!
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php).+)$ index.php?request2=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^((?!index\\.php.+)$'